# DEFINE_SPINLOCK(...) spinlock_t argument error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I'm currently working on a project for class that includes a kernel-based implementation of a semaphore. Instead of using DEFINE_SPINLOCK(sem_lock); as a global variable in /kernel/sys.c, I've created a scheme where the semaphore struct holds a spinlock_t variable (masked as void * in user space) in order to allow different semaphores the opportunity to down()/up() independently (which should translate to more efficient code with less busy waiting). I make a syscall to initialize a semaphore, passing a pointer to the struct. However, I'm having an error with one line, when initializing the semaphore's spinlock_t.

I've contacted my professor, who said for the purposes of this assignment just to use a coarse-implementation with a global spinlock definition. However, it's hard to let this go. While I obviously don't mind taking that route, I still want to understand why my implementation doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the error:

```
    CC      kernel/sys.o
kernel/sys.c: In function 'sys_cs1550_sem_init':
kernel/sys.c:2491: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '->' token
kernel/sys.c:2491: error: expected expression before '->' token
make[1]: *** [kernel/sys.o] Error 1
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

I've tried the following:

```
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(sem->sem_lock);  
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(&(sem->sem_lock));  
DEFINE_SPINLOCK((&(sem->sem_lock)));  
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(*(sem->sem_lock));  
spinlock_t *lock = &(sem->sem_lock);  
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(lock);
```

My code for the semaphore struct in /kernel/sys.c:

```
/*
* Initialize a semaphore with the creation of it's spinlock.
* The idea is to avoid having spinlocks in user space, by making
* the process as opaque as possible. Our lock is defined in the kernel as a spinlock_t,
* but as a void* in userspace. This allows us to have more than one semaphore as needed.
*/
struct cs1550_sem{
    spinlock_t *sem_lock;                   //The lock for our semaphore.
    int available_resources;                //Total # of available resources.
    struct cs1550_pnode *process_list;      //Pointer to the first node of our linked list.
};
```

My code for the semaphore initialization syscall in /kernel/sys.c:

```
asmlinkage long sys_cs1550_sem_init(struct cs1550_sem *sem, int resource_cap){
    DEFINE_SPINLOCK(sem->sem_lock);         //Define our lock.
    sem->process_list = NULL;               //Ensure we have a 'stopping point' when dequeueing.
    sem->available_resources = resource_cap;
    return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(sys_cs1550_sem_init);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use this macro in that way.

```
// spinlock_types.h
#define DEFINE_SPINLOCK(x)      spinlock_t x = __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(x)
```

Your struct may look like this:

```
struct cs1550_sem{
    spinlock_t sem_lock;                   //The lock for our semaphore.
    int available_resources;                //Total # of available resources.
    struct cs1550_pnode *process_list;      //Pointer to the first node of our linked list.
};
```

And initialization:

```
asmlinkage long sys_cs1550_sem_init(struct cs1550_sem *sem, int resource_cap){
    spin_lock_init(&sem->sem_lock);         //Define our lock.
    sem->process_list = NULL;               //Ensure we have a 'stopping point' when dequeueing.
    sem->available_resources = resource_cap;
    return 0;
}
```

Take a look at lesson 3 of https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spinlocks.txt and [spin_lock_init(...)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h) (line 295)

Comment: So the solution for initializing the spinlock locally instead of globally in the semaphore struct would be to take out the macro and just use the code: 
''sem->sem_lock = __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(sem->sem_lock);''
?

Comment: Hmm, missed that. Thanks so much for your help, I'll try that implementation (with the appropriate dereference) and see how it works. Either way, I now know why my previous attempts weren't working. I sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit - helped a ton. Hopefully my syscall implementations were solid, should be smooth sailing from here on out.